# Error creating bigquery subscription to pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm seeing an error creating a bq subscription from pub/sub.
`` Field `data` not found in table schema ``

command: `gcloud pubsub subscriptions create subId --topic=topicId --bigquery-table=projectId.dataset.table`

I created a table and now I want to create a subscription that writes to bigquery from pub/sub

Comment: Does your BigQuery table have a column named "data"?

Comment: No, I don't have any columns with that name

Comment: Can you try again after adding a column called data of type BYTES or STRING to the [Bigquery table](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#properties_subscription)?

Comment: Oh interesting, when you create a table using topic schema, you still have to define a column?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set `--use-table-schema` or `--use-topic-schema`, then you need to have a column of type `BYTES`, `STRING`, or `JSON` with the name `data`. See the [documentation on BigQuery subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-properties#bigquery).

Comment: Oh I see, yes I found it works when I'm using --use-table-schema and give it a schema, however when I use --use-topic-schema, how do I pass json as a param?